# Problem with swapping values ​between arrays

Tags: arrays, c

I have this problem to solve:

> Write a program that reads an array with 20 int elements. Then, in a
> function, separate the array into two other arrays, one with positive
> elements and zero and one with negative values. Solve the extreme
> hypotheses, like the 20 elements are of a single type.

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TAM 10

int verify(int a[], int n)
{
    int verify1, verify2;
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > 0)
        {
            verify1++;
        }
        else if (a[i] < 0)
        {
            verify2++;
        }
    }
    if (verify1 > 0 && verify2 > 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

void change(int a[], int x)
{
    int positive[TAM], negative[TAM];
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] >= 0)
        {
            positive[i] = a[i];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] < 0)
        {
            negative[i] = a[i];
        }
    }

    printf("--------------- Array positive ---------------\n\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", positive[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("--------------- Array negative ---------------\n\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", negative[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int a[TAM];
    int cont;

    for(int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        printf("Inform a value for %d position\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    system("cls");

    printf("Normal Array\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    cont = verify(a, TAM);

    if (cont == 0)
    {
        printf("You had informed only positive or negative values\n\n");
        printf("BYE\n\n\n");
        system("pause");
        abort();
    }
    else if (cont == 1)
    {
        change(a, TAM);
    }
}
```

I am getting these results:

[image]

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand

Comment: The problem is you aren't keeping track of how many values you've written to the positive and negative arrays, and are just using the same index as the source array.  But you should only advance those indices after you write a value to them.  For example, a the very start, all indices should be (pos_ix = neg_ix = src_ix = 0).  Then you look at `a[src_ix]`.  Suppose it's -5.  Then you want to do `negative[neg_ix++] = a[src_ix]` (with `src_ix` presumably being incremented by the loop).  After both incremenets, you should have `neg_ix = 1, pos_ix = 0, src_ix = 1`.

Comment: Since you're effectively using `src_ix` for everything, you're leaving holes in the `negative` and `positive` arrays, and those holes contain undefined values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use the same index into the source array and the positive and negative destination arrays. As observed on the output, the entries in the target array are uninitialized and contain random data in places where you did not store values.

Furthermore, you do not initialize `verify1` nor `verify2` so the `verify` function has undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TAM 10

int verify(int a[], int n) {
    int verify1 = 0, verify2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] >= 0) {
            verify1++;
        } else {
            verify2++;
        }
    }
    return (verify1 > 0 && verify2 > 0);
}

void change(int a[], int n) {
    int positive[n], negative[n];
    int len1 = 0, len2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] >= 0) {
            positive[len1++] = a[i];
        } else {
            negative[len2++] = a[i];
        }
    }

    printf("--------------- Array positive ---------------\n\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) {
        printf("%d ", positive[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    printf("--------------- Array negative ---------------\n\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < len2; i++) {
        printf("%d ", negative[i]);
    }
}

int main() [
    int a[TAM] = { 0 };
    int cont;

    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        printf("Inform a value for %d position\n", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    system("cls");

    printf("Normal Array\n\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    cont = verify(a, TAM);

    if (cont == 0) {
        printf("You had informed only positive or negative values\n\n");
        printf("BYE\n\n\n");
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    } else {
        change(a, TAM);
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
}
```